# How to get the output of a shell command to a React frontend through a Flask RESTful API?

Tags: reactjs, flask, paramiko

I am trying to get the output of a shell command to a React frontend through a Flask RESTful API.

```
class SerVer(Resource):
    def put(self):
        args = cred_put_args.parse_args()
        cred = args
        return cred, 201

for it in cred:
    client = SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
    client.load_system_host_keys()
    client.connect(it.ip, it.uname, it.pwd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ps aux')
    psaux = (f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')

    def get(self):
        return {'data': psaux}, 203

api.add_resource(SerVer, '/request', '/psaux')
```

The GET request is sent from react, like so:

```
  const [psaux, psauxSet] = useState();

  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get("http://127.0.0.1:5000/request").then((res) => {
      const i = res.data;
      console.log(i);
      psauxSet(i);
    });
  }, []);
```

I understand the problem is variable scoping. I had it working at some point, that I'm trying to reproduce :)

Comment: What error do you get? What is the result that you didn't expect?

Comment: GET http://127.0.0.1:5000/request 405 (METHOD NOT ALLOWED)
dispatchXhrRequest @ xhr.js:175
xhrAdapter @ xhr.js:20
dispatchRequest @ dispatchRequest.js:40
Promise.then (async)
request @ Axios.js:64
Axios.<computed> @ Axios.js:79
wrap @ bind.js:11
(anonymous) @ App.js:12
commitHookEffectList @ react-dom.development.js:18059
commitPassiveHookEffects @ react-dom.development.js:18086
callCallback @ react-dom.development.js:147
Uncaught (in promise) Error: Request failed with status code 405

Comment: Have a look [here](https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/405-method-not-allowed). It might help

Answer (score 0):

Because the indentation of the code is wrong, it should probably be:

```
from flask import Response

class SerVer(Resource):
    def put(self):
        args = cred_put_args.parse_args()
        cred = args
        return cred, 201

        for it in cred:
            client = SSHClient()
            client.set_missing_host_key_policy(AutoAddPolicy())
            client.load_system_host_keys()
            client.connect(it.ip, it.uname, it.pwd)
            stdin, stdout, stderr = client.exec_command('ps aux')
            psaux = (f'STDOUT: {stdout.read().decode("utf8")}')

    def get(self):
        res = {
            'data': 'psaux'
        }
        return Response(mimetype="application/json", response=json.dumps(res), status=203)
```

Pay also attention when you add your Resource object (SerVer) to the api object, take a look [here](https://flask-restful.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#endpoints)

Comment: now I have a { "data": "psaux" } instead of my data :(

Comment: The psaux variable is not defined in that scope, i don't know what you have to do, but this is the correct way to handle the request with flask